# How to replace different phrases with one word - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace

While learning python, I was messing around with the replace() method and tried making this program:

```py
message = raw_input("Message to find the part of speech: ")
coordconj = "for" or "and" or "nor" or "but" or "or" or "yet" or "so"

print message.replace(coordconj, "coordinating conjunction")
```

If I run this with the input "name1 for name2". The output is "name1 coordinating conjunction name2" But with "name1 and name2" as the input it prints "name1 and name2"

I also tried:

```py
message = raw_input("Message to find the part of speech: ")


print message.replace("for" or "and" or "nor" or "but" or "or" or "yet" or "so", "coordinating conjunction")
```

But that didn't work either. It only replaces "for" with "coordinating conjunction". Is there any way to have all words in the variable `coorcon` be replaced with "coordinating conjunction" without using a bunch of if statements? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Briefly: `re.sub` is probably the easiest way to do that, and I suggest you try printing the value of `coordconj`, because `or` doesn't do anything close to what you think it does.

Comment: Refresh the page. The links are placed between the title and body.

Comment: I can help you a little by letting you know that your expression `"for" or "and" or "nor" ...`  is valid but not what you want.  Rather, you are doing a logical operation and due to [short-cicruit logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032801/whats-the-value-of-short-circuit-of-python/43032929#43032929), the first string is being returned.  That is, your logical expression evaluates to just "for".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
"for" or "and" or "nor" or "but" or "or" or "yet" or "so"
```

is just `"for"` since a non-empty string is Truthy in Python and `or` is evaluated lazily.

You can check in Python console :

```
>>> "for" or "and" or "nor" or "but" or "or" or "yet" or "so"
'for'
```

Here's a possible way to solve your problem :

```
import re

def find_speech_part(matchobj):
  word = matchobj.group(0)
  if word.lower() in ["for","and","nor","but","or","yet","so"]:
    return "coordinating conjunction"
  else:
    return word

print(re.sub('\w+', find_speech_part, 'For A but not for B because neither C nor D'))
# coordinating conjunction A coordinating conjunction not coordinating conjunction B because neither C coordinating conjunction D
```

It's been adapted from this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42747503/6419007).

Comment: I see, I'll try something else. Thanks

Comment: There's really no need to answer common duplicates like this - you didn't even provide a solution. This would've been better suited as a comment.

Comment: There's also _really_ no need to copy existing answers.

Comment: All of the originals will help the OP. That's why I put them there. If OP doesn't understand some of the terms used in those answers, they should _research_ them, not wait for someone else who's just as likely as they to use this site as a coding service.

Comment: When I find the anonymous user who downvoted your post, I'll let them know.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: If you downvote someone and think you have a valid reason to do so, just say so and be done with it. That's fine with me. Don't try to hide behind SO's anonymous voting.

Comment: Maybe it's the same person who's been downvoting my questions. I'll keep an eye out for them.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: It's harder to detect sarcasm on the Internet. If you mean to imply I participate in revenge downvoting : I don't. It's childish and encourages the exact same behaviour I'm complaining about.